# How to show Dialog in onCreate method?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to show Dialog in onCreate method ? Is that possible at all, I tried but I got leaked window exception. Can anyone suggest me anything ?

Answer (score 5):

you can use ProgressDialog Class with the Help of Handler Class. This way you can achieve what you want to do.

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(loginAct,"Process ", "please wait....",true,true);

new Thread ( new Runnable()
{
     public void run()
     {
      // your loading code goes here
     }
}).start();


     Handler progressHandler = new Handler() 
     {

         public void handleMessage(Message msg1) 
         {

             progDailog.dismiss();
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

I am sure that you might be using a bad context there. To show the Dialog on the `UI(specific)` Activity don't use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()`. Just create the instance using `Activity_Name.this` and you will be able to show the Dialog.

Comment: If dialog is to be displayed in TAB, use getParent() as Context.