# How to attach a Progress Dialog box to an onClick event

Tags: android, android-activity

First time posting here, so go easy on me. :)

I am trying to do something that (I think) should be simple. I am loading another activity within the **onClick** event of a **OnClickListener** that is attached to a button:

```
public class Prime extends Activity {

    ....

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prime);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_start_button);
        Button scoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_score_button);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent start = new Intent("com.mazam.eikaiwa.Modules");
                startActivity(start);
            }
        });

        scoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                .....
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now, the Modules activity that I am loading via the startButton is a bit heavy with the XML layout, and takes about 2-3 seconds to load. I would like to place a progress dialogue when the button is clicked to notify the user until the intent is fully loaded.

I have been able to make this work perfectly with the information I found on a site (I am sorry I don't remember the name or location) using a separate thread and overriding the onKeyDown function. However I couldn't extend this to the onClick function.

So, my question is how can I display a progress dialogue when the user clicks the startButton and have it disappear when the Modules activity is fully loaded?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ProgressDialog Class with the Help of Handler Class. Please visit my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078356/how-to-show-dialog-in-oncreate-method/9078502#9078502).