# how to pop up a dialog when tapping on a Map marker?

Tags: android, marker, dialog

I want to display a dialog box when tapping a marker on my map. i could set the marker on the map, but i am unable to pop up the dialog box which should contain the some description about the marked place. I tried overriding onTouchEvent(), but then the box appeared only when tapping the exact point. But what i want is to display the dialog box when touching any point within the marker. Could anybody pls help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using a dialog why not use map balloons https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, i have class extend ItemizedOverlay    you just override  `onTap`

```
public class PlaceItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {



    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(final int index) {


      final OverlayItem oi = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle("your title");
      dialog.setMessage("youmessage");
      dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
      dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
      });
      dialog.show();
      return true;

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use or refer to MapViewBalloons project

[example project](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

Answer (score 0):

You can display an AlertDialog for this with the help of Handler Class. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078356/how-to-show-dialog-in-oncreate-method/9078502#9078502).

Comment: just display the ProgressDialog on its click event.