# How to know when activity finished loading?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, progressdialog, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to implement ProgressDialog that will load all the activity.
So I added this line to the onCreate() method:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Waiting...", "Please wait five seconds...");
```

but is start loading after all the content was loaded, and its not stop because I don't know where add the line:

```
pd,dismiss();
```

So there is any built-in method that called when the activity is show up (like in iOS - viewDidAppear) and another built-in method that called when the activity is finished loading and all the content were loaded?

Comment: What do you mean by load all the activity?

Comment: @dhuma1981 in the activity I get content from web and its takes a while...

Comment: do you know all data is finished loading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display progress bar while loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844116/display-progress-bar-while-loading)

Comment: @Nir first get the data using asyctask and there are methods available where you can dismiss the your loading dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

what doest it mean load all the activity ? I think you are on the wrong way. You can`t load all the activities, but you can call an intent what is launch an activity. In this case the activity lifeCycle comes in the picture.

please check out this:
http://www.mikestratton.net/assets/android_activity_lifecycle.png

If you would like to us progressdialog, and load any content on the background thread read this:
[progressDialog in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538338/progressdialog-in-asynctask)

Good example who to handle dialog in Android:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/
please don`t try to  load all of the activities. Never ever call new MyActivity(); NEVER

Answer (score 0):

**"The activity I get content from web"**

This line i get from your comments which means you are fetching some data in that time you need to show ProgressDialog.

If this is correct then you might be using `AsyncTask` for the `webservice`

So you don't need to show dialog from your onCreate method. You need to show your ProgressDialog from AsyncTask `onPreExecute()` method.

Once it is completed you need to `cancel dialog` in `onPostExecute` method

**EDIT:**
AsyncTask Reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
This is perfect tutorial.

Comment: You can give a tutorial that explain how to exactly do this thing?

Comment: You just google it. You can get many example. anyway check my edit

Answer (score -1):

You can dismiss your Dialog in `onStop()`

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Or you can dismiss in `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
      pd.dismiss();
}
```