# Android: Progress Bar to Upload Data to the Server

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

In my application some data is there which is wrapped into an object.
I am sending this object to the server. Everything work correctly.
Here I want to show progress bar when the data is loading to the server.
For this I am using this code:

```
ProgressThread progThread;
ProgressDialog progDialog;

int typeBar;
int delay = 40; 
int maxBarValue = 200;
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 1:
        progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progDialog.setMax(maxBarValue);
        progDialog.setMessage("Data uploading to the Server..");
        progThread = new ProgressThread(handler);
        progThread.start();
        return progDialog;

    default:
        return null;
    }
}


final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
        // and update the progress bar.
        int total = msg.getData().getInt("total");
        progDialog.setProgress(total);
        if (total <= 0) {
            dismissDialog(typeBar);
            progThread.setState(ProgressThread.DONE);
        }
    }
};

private class ProgressThread extends Thread {

    final static int DONE = 0;
    final static int RUNNING = 1;

    Handler mHandler;
    int mState;
    int total;

    ProgressThread(Handler h) {
        mHandler = h;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        mState = RUNNING;
        total = maxBarValue;
        while (mState == RUNNING) {

            connectServerClass.saveOnServer(Object);

            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("total", total);
            msg.setData(b);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            total--; // Count down
        }
    }
    public void setState(int state) {
        mState = state;
    }
}
```

When user click on button then:

```
typeBar = 1;
showDialog(typeBar);
```

connectServerClass.saveOnServer(Object)
by the above line I am sending object to the server. Actually I am sending data to the other class which is connectServerClass and this class send object to the server.
but this code not work correctly. This code connect to the server lots of time.

I use the following Code :

```
private class Uploader extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Integer>
    {
        private List<File> files;
        private boolean canceled;
        private int uploaded;
        private Account account;
        private ProgressDialog uploadSeekBar;

        public Uploader(Account a, List<File> files)
        {
            this.account = a;
            this.files = files;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            uploadSeekBar.setMax(files.size());
            uploadSeekBar.setProgress(0);
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //Error: the method setVisibility is undefined
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, result + " files uploaded", // Error: Upload cannot be resolved to a type
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            // XXX need a way to actually cancel the last upload
            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "canceling upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            this.canceled = true;
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            uploaded = 0;
            try
            {
                Iterator<File> it = this.files.iterator();
                while (!canceled && it.hasNext())
                {
                    File file = it.next();
                    it.remove();

                    String msg = "";

                    try
                    {
                        if (debugMode)  // what is this debugMode
                        {
                                                //Put your uploading code here.
                            msg = ("fake uploading " + file);
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } else
                        {
                            msg = ("uploading: " + file);
                            controller.uploadFile(file, this.account); //Error: controller cannot be resolved
                        }

                        uploaded++;
                        publishProgress(msg);

                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        controller.te("error uploading file: " + file);
                        controller.te("error uploading file: " + e);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                publishProgress("error uploading: " + e);
            }

            return uploaded;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... strings)
        {
            uploadSeekBar.setProgress(uploaded);
            updateUploadMessage(files.size());
            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, strings[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Error: The method updateUploadMessage(int) is undefined for the type FirstActivity.Uploader 
        }
    }
```

But I facing some error which I mention as comment in the right side of that line. Please suggest me.

Comment: my this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9078502/996493) might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will strongly recommend you to Use AsyncTask.

Below Code snippet will help you on How your AsyncTask should look like.

```
package org.sample;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

    private class Uploader extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Integer>
    {
        private List<File> files;
        private boolean canceled;
        private int uploaded;

        public Uploader(Account a, List<File> files)
        {
            this.account = a;
            this.files = files;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            uploadSeekBar.setMax(files.size());
            uploadSeekBar.setProgress(0);
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, result + " files uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            // XXX need a way to actually cancel the last upload
            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "canceling upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            this.canceled = true;
            uploadSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            uploaded = 0;
            try
            {
                Iterator<File> it = this.files.iterator();
                while (!canceled && it.hasNext())
                {
                    File file = it.next();
                    it.remove();

                    String msg = "";

                    try
                    {
                        if (debugMode)
                        {
                                                //Put your uploading code here.
                            msg = ("fake uploading " + file);
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } else
                        {
                            msg = ("uploading: " + file);
                            controller.uploadFile(file, this.account);
                        }

                        uploaded++;
                        publishProgress(msg);

                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        controller.te("error uploading file: " + file);
                        controller.te("error uploading file: " + e);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                publishProgress("error uploading: " + e);
            }

            return uploaded;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... strings)
        {
            uploadSeekBar.setProgress(uploaded);
            updateUploadMessage(files.size());
            Toast.makeText(Upload.this, strings[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanx Vipul.... So I need to write code into  doInBackground method that is connectServerClass.saveOnServer(Object)

Comment: Perfect!! You can write uploading code in doInBackground and once done you can show success/failure message in onPostExecute!!

Comment: @VinitVikash If it solved your problem then you can mark this answer as Accepted So it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Hi Vipul .. I tried your code (mention above which I edited in my question)and some error is there. Please Solve it ...

Comment: @ Vipul I got the thing that how to put progress bar. But one more problem is there what the code I need to write into doInBackground() and in onProgressUpdate() method. Please help me..
I putted this problem in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979739/android-progress-bar-to-upload-object-into-server#comment14340402_10979739

Comment: @ Vipul Shah I am till waiting for the solution...
If you have any idea then please help me ...
because here I totally stack ...
and because of this my application is in developing phase ...

Comment: @VinitVikashFirst you should work on Accepting Answers.your question was Android: Progress Bar to Upload Data to the Server? You have got answers on how to show progress and what should be the approach.you must accpet answer which suits you.then post another question with query.

Comment: @VipulShah Can you please explain how would I use your code for a single image uploading on server, using progress bar at bottom. As your code seems to be work for multiple files as it increases count for every file uploading and updating the progress bar by count.