# Android: Progress Bar to upload Object into server

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I want to put progress bar when object is sent to the server. But I don't know what the code I need to write in **doInBackground()** method and what the code in **onProgressUpdate()** 
.

Here Client Socket program is used to send Object to the Server.

Code (Inner Class):

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setProgress(0);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

}
}
```

So, here what I need to write in **doInBackground()** and in **onProgressUpdate()**

I have one object **serverObject** which I need to send to the Server.

Currently I am using following code to send object to the server without any progress bar:

```
Socket s = new Socket("xxx.xx.xx.xxx", xxx);

//to send object to the server
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(serverObject);
oos.flush();
if (s != null) {s.close();}
if (oos != null) {oos.close();}
```

how I write this code into **doInBackground()** method and keep track up to what % data is send.

How to get the size of the object. In lot of site they mention size of the File. But in my case this is a object.

And one more thing to execute this I need to write :

```
new DownloadFileAsync().execute(params);
```

So how I get this params.

Comment: In your case Params could be the URL of the server at which you want to upload your file. You can also call execute() without passing params, just modify the AsyncTask's parameters accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi here is the answer of your question please find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501550/how-can-i-make-an-android-app-communicate-with-a-web-server-over-the-internet/9503995#9503995)

this is the example of how you can upload the file to server.

here is the example you can add the progress bar.

```
ProgressDialog pd;
private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
         case 1:
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "uploading...", "Please Wait..", true,false);
            pd.setCancelable(false);

          break;
         case 2:
         pd.dismiss();
         break;
        }

}
};
 new Thread(new Runnable() {                
            @Override
            public void run() {                     
                try {                   
                         handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                         executeMultipartPost(bitmap,filename.jpg);
                         handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   

            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: but this link not mention any progress bar.

Comment: this one should be a comment. it is not an answer

Comment: @MunishKapoor one error is there in switch code, the argument in Switch(msg): Error:Cannot switch on a value of type Message. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted