# My ProgressDialog doesn't dismiss even after the view has been loaded.

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to show a Progress-Dialog before my view has been loaded. 
First i wrote the code in onCreate() but the dialog doesn't appear in that case. So i wrote it in onResume() but in this case, it doesn't disappear even after the view has been loaded. can anyone tell whats going wrong here?

```
              protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait...", true); 
    //dialog.cancel();
    new Thread() 
    {
      public void run() 
      {

         try
           {

            sleep(1500);

      // do the background process or any work that takes time to see progress dialog

           }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag",e.getMessage());
        }
    // dismiss the progressdialog   
     dialog.dismiss();
     }
    }.start();
    citySelected.setText(fetchCity);
    spinner.setSelection(getBG);
}
```

Comment: write dialog.dismiss(); line outside thread code.

Comment: my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9078502/996493) might give you some logic part

Answer (score 1):

You cant update UI(which is in main UIthread) from other threads. If you want to run any query in the background, you can use AsyncTask.

In onPreExecute method, show dialog and onPostExecute you can dismiss the dialog.

If you want to use Thread, then update UI using handlers.

Using AsyncTask

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

In Activity onCreate Method,

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
    task.execute();
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it pauses the screen to the same activity and then the next view is loaded without the dialog being shown!

Comment: if you want to start new activity after completing this, then start new activity in onPostExecute method. Dont call in oncreate itself. I think, you are calling startActivity in onCreate after task.execute(). Put it in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask. It is better than Thread

```
private class DownloadingProgressTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowDescription.this);
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
         this.dialog.show();

    }
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
                downloadFile(b.getString("URL"));
                return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("tag", "error", e);
                return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

         if (dialog.isShowing()) {
         dialog.dismiss();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use `Asynctask` ......... but if you still want same or want to `know the solution only` then can try

```
new Thread() 
    {
      public void run() 
      {

         try
           {

            sleep(1500);

      // do the background process or any work that takes time to see progress dialog

           }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("tag",e.getMessage());
        }




  YourActivity.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
                         @Override
                         public void run(){
                             // dismiss the progressdialog   
                              dialog.dismiss();
                        });





     }
    }.start();
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but still it doesn't work! The dialog won't dismiss.